# SPO 2013 - Community Site Reputation Levels

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, community-site

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

We were wondering if it's possible to add more ranks than the default of 5 in the Sharepoint Online community site? If it's possible, how can it be done? I tried to look around the UI and settings but couldn't find anything about adding more ranks.

I'm grateful for any solutions regarding this issue! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated personally about this matter and the answer is no, out of the box.

You can use the badge system but not automatically and any user can only have one badge at a time. Badges are assigned manually and not automatically.

The community is a great improvement from the old discussion board, but still no cigar.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer! Do you know if there are any custom solutions to add more ranks? Via some script or code changes or something like that? :-)

Comment: I do not think it is that easy, and I have not found any codes like that available on the net. It is about tweaking the mechanism of badges, not just some appearance. If such a thing is possible I believe it's the job of a developer that did not bother to share this improvement publicly